# Locally cyclic subgroups of a hyperbolic group

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

How can we show that locally cyclic subgroups (ie. groups whose finitely generated proper subgroups are cyclic) of a hyperbolic group are cyclic?

Comment: Such subgroups are solvable, and the result follows from the solvable subgroup theorem.  There might be an easier way, though.

Comment: @SteveD: Is it immediate that such subgroups are solvable? I don't see why...

Comment: The group is abelian...

Comment: @SteveD: Of course... Thank you.

Comment: OK, I now see a much easier proof of this, using the fact that abelian subgroups should be quasi-convex. Basically, take any element in your subgroup; then its centralizer is quasi-convex, and hence hyperbolic.  In particular, it is finitely generated, and thus its center - as the intersection of quasi-convex subgroups - is also hyperbolic. This is a finite-generated abelian group, which is either finite or virtually cyclic.  Intersecting with your original subgroup finishes.  For a reference, see http://berstein.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/quasi-convex-subgroups-of-hyperbolic-groups/

Comment: @SteveD: Thank you for your comment. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested:

To prove this, one can use the fact that abelian subgroups of a hyperbolic group should be quasi-convex; this is because centralizers are quasi-convex.  Thus the abelian subgroup is finitely generated, and your subgroup is in fact hyperbolic.  I don't want to flesh this argument out too much, because it is already nicely written up [here](http://berstein.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/quasi-convex-subgroups-of-hyperbolic-groups/).

I had remarked in my comments above that the Solvable Subgroup Theorem also accomplishes this, but for that to work you need an isometric action on a CAT(0) space.